# Include header in multiple .csv file with cat linux

Tags: command-line

I need to include a .csv header in multiple .csv files at once by switching the name to:

> originalname1c.csv, originalname2c.csv, originalname3c.csv

Currently, the procedure is done as follows:

```
cat header.csv originalname1.csv > originalname1c.csv
cat header.csv originalname2.csv > originalname2c.csv
cat header.csv originalname3.csv > originalname3c.csv
```

Etc.

Is it possible to add header to multiple files as in the above example in a single command?

additional one: what if the filenames were random? keeping the rule from: anyname.csv to anynamec.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any POSIX compliant shell

```
for f in *.csv; do
  cat header.csv "$f" > "${f%.csv}c.csv"
done
```

The `${f%.csv}` construct removes the `.csv` extension from the expansion of `$f` so that you can add back `c.csv` to the basename.